# Click a button to open a Fragment?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have a ViewPager in which I am able to view between 4 different tabs (which are fragments) I created. In one of my fragments, I want to have a button that will, after I click a button on that page, replace that view with another fragment. Now I don't want to swipe to another tab, I just merely want to replace the view of the current fragment when I press that button. Here is my attempt, but I'm not sure why when I click my button, nothing happens. If anyone could help me that would be great. Thanks!

This is the Fragment I call to create the view and the button I want to press.

ManualSelection.java

```
public class ManualSelection extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_manual_selection, container, false);
        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ManualSelectionListView.class);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Button listViewGenerated = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.manual_generate);
        listViewGenerated.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.listView_manual, new ManualSelectionListView());
                ft.commit();
            }

        });
    }
}
```

And here is the Fragment I want to create

ManualSelectionListView.java

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class ManualSelectionListView extends Fragment {

static final String[] MOBILE_OS =
        new String[] { "Android", "iOS", "WindowsMobile", "Blackberry"};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false);

    ListView lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    lv.setAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(getActivity(),MOBILE_OS));

    return rootView;
}
}
```

And here are my XML files:

activity_manual_selection.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ecs160.homestay.ManualSelection"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentTest"> 

 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Generate"
    android:id="@+id/manual_generate"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="generateListView"/>
```

And here is the XML file called listview.xml that contains `R.id.listView_manual`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView_manual">

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I get nothing displayed when I hit "Generate." Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: is the click event happening. try keeping the click event in onstart instead thats what I do

Comment: @IllegalArgument it creates an error when I try to open the ViewPager

Comment: @IllegalArgument There is no error, nothing happens when I hit the button and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity you should create this:

```
public void generateListView(View v){
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.listView_manual, new ManualSelectionListView());
    ft.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to get the Button id from your main activity which will return null

```
        Button listViewGenerated = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.manual_generate);
```

Button `manual_generate` is located in your `activity_manual_selection` layout not in your Main activity's layout you cant get view from different layout or else it will return null

**solution:**

Get the Button's id from your fragment's layout

```
public class ManualSelection extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_manual_selection, container, false);
    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ManualSelectionListView.class);

   Button listViewGenerated = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.manual_generate);
    listViewGenerated.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.listView_manual, new ManualSelectionListView());
            ft.commit();
        }

    });

    return rootView;
}
```

remove `onActivityCreated`

Comment: I tried to implement your changes, but when I click the button, nothing happens just like before. Any ideas why?

Comment: @user1567909 try to debug inside of the onClick if click is hapenning

Comment: I doubt you are seeing the button if you are then first apply click event in listview then try button so step by step

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I just put a debug statement inside onClick and the click is indeed occuring. I think it has to do with how I did the fragment management... or how I am replacing the views... Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @user1567909 R.id.listView_manual is wrong it should be id from your activity layout

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Hm, I'm confused because I thought I did declare the id from my activity layout: I specified `listView_manual` to be the id in the linear layout of the xml file (the file is called listview.xml) I wanted to replace the current fragment view with.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin nope, no error. when I click the button, nothing seems to happen. No errors or anything are generated.

Comment: @user1567909 it is actually happening cause you said button is clicking. I think that fragment is changing but you just cant see it

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin is there a way I can see the fragment change?

Comment: @user1567909 try to test without a View pager and if it works from there then you can implement it in your Viewpagers

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin what do you mean implement it in my ViewPagers?

Comment: @user1567909 what I mean is that just try it without viewpager if it work the changing of fragment.