# ListView in a new activity android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i would like to create a listView with images and text but not in the main activity! heres where i am at, i have created a splash activity for when the app starts, then the main activity displays and this is where all the buttons on my ui are like a main menu, i would like to use an intent at the press of a button on my main menu that will then display the list view!
would i have to make a new blank activity for the listView to show? and write the code in there? i guess what i am saying is i dont want the listView to display as my main menu in main activity!
sorry if i have confused you with this, i am still new to development and stack over flow. Your help is greatly appreciated thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a fragment. Intents are not very efficient, it would better for you to use a fragment for the listview. Search up fragments on slidnerd or check the [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html). If you do not want to use a fragment, then yes you would have to make a new blank activity and have the intent lead to this activity.

Comment: thank you for your reply, with the use of a fragment would this be possible to display the fragment list from a button press at my main mainu?

Comment: Yes it would be possible. Use an onClick Listener to do this. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102057/click-a-button-to-open-a-fragment) explains it at well but make sure you understand fragments first.

Comment: sganu, thank you for all your help, i taken your advice and went with fragments! seems a much easier and better way and has solved my problem! thank you for pointing me in the right direction